# Write a function to calculate the PDF in R?

Tags: r, function, probability

I'm to write a function to calculate the PDF of and it's been suggested that I use the if/elseif/else statements. However whenever I try and do so, I keep getting error messages but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong?
This is the PDF that the function is supposed to calculate:

fx = 0.3 if (0<=x<1)
     0.1 if (1<=x<2)
     0.25 if (2<=x<3)
     0.15 if (3<=x<4)
     0.2 if (4<=x<5)
     0 otherwise

This is my code:

```
    fx = function(x)
    { 
    if (0<=x<1) {
    pdf=0.3
    } elseif (1<=x<2) {
    pdf=0.1
    } elseif (2<=x<3) {
    pdf=0.25
    } elseif (3<=x<4) {
    pdf=0.15
    } elseif (4<=x<5) {
    pdf=0.2
    } else 
    pdf=0

    pdf
    }
```

I have checked my '}' but they all seem appropriately placed. I've tried changing 'pdf' to 'fx' but that doesn't work. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
fx <- function(x) c(0, 0.3,0.1,0.25,0.15,0.20, 0)[findInterval(x, c(-Inf, 0:5, Inf))]
```

The `findInterval` function returns the position of its first argument from within a sequence of intervals defined by its second argument and can be used to select a probability from a vector. The values outside the domain of support get chosen as 0 values as requested. It is particularly useful in cases like this where the lower bounds are closed, since the default for the `cut` function is to have upper bounds as closed.

Comment: I tried your code but I got an error message about the ']' and then when I tried to do fx(4), it said that the function could not be found?

Comment: @Mathlete It's just a typo; you just need another ) before the last ]. I'm sure DWin will fix it shortly.

Comment: Incidentally, what was wrong with my code? This is obviously much more efficient, but I'd just like to know where I was going wrong.

Comment: The expression `1<=x<2` throws the error. There is no parsing rule that allows that expression to be valid. The "<" operators are always dyadic. (There exist hacks to overcome this, however.)

Comment: Could I use a similar approach to generate a sequence of points (X,Y) uniformly distributed in (0,a) x (0,b) say, until one of the points lies in the curve of fx?

Comment: Furthermore there is no `elseif` function. To your last question: what does it mean to say "one of the points lies in the curve of fx"?

Comment: @DWin I meant if I were to plot the function fx, generate a sequence of points etc and if one of these points lay in the region under the curve?

Comment: I guess it would be possible. I would think you would need to restrict the x values to [0,5] and it's not clear what meaning this exercise would ahve, so maybe posing another question? This one seems beaten to death.

Comment: @DWin I think you're right. Just for the record, how would I restrict the x values (I tried xlim=c(0,5) but to no avail) and plot fx?

Comment: I was assuming you would generate the x-members with runif(N, 0,5) and the y-members of the tuples with runif(N, 0,1), but then I asked myself what meaning could be attached to the result, which was why I asked for a purpose or motivation for the exercise. (I think this should end the comments.)

Answer (score 3):

there were two problems with your code

1/   Expressions such as a <= x < b are legal in maths but not in code. In code you need a <=x && x < b

2/   You need to use "else if" rather than "elseif"

This code works

```
fx = function(x)
{ 
if (0<=x && x<1) {
pdf=0.3    
} else if (1<=x && x<2) {
pdf=0.1
} else if (2<= x&& x<3) {
pdf=0.25
} else if (3<=x && x<4) {
pdf=0.15
} else if (4<= x&& x<5) {
pdf=0.2
} else 
pdf=0

pdf
}
```

Also, as an optimization, you should only repeatedly need to test that x < b, not the a. And you shouldn't need a pdf variable. This leads to the following code, but I'm guessing that the built-in function that was posted above is more efficient.

```
fx = function(x)
{ 
if (x<0) 0
else if (x<1) 0.3
else if (x<2) 0.1
else if (x<3) 0.25
else if (x<4) 0.15
else if (x<5) 0.2
else 0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `stepfun` to create a step function (which is what your PDF is)

```
fx <- stepfun(x = 0:5, y = c(0,0.3,0.1,0.25,0.15,0.20,0))
```

If you want a vectorized  version, then you can use `Vectorize`

```
vfx <- Vectorize(fx)
```

`stepfun` objects can be plotted nicely using `plot` (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/16072697/1385941 for a related example)